# Using aws-cli s3 list-objects with max-items and query LastModified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to get the latest items uploaded to a bucket. I have this command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "Contents[?LastModified>='$TODAY'].Key[]" --max-items 10
```

It returns "None". I am guessing that it first gets 10 items from the bucket and then it applies the query. If I execute it with --query or --max-items individually they work properly returning some items. I have tried both list-objects and list-objects-v2.

Is there any workaround use both of them at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `--query` operations are performed on the results *after* they come back from S3.

Therefore, S3 will return the first 10 items (as listed alphabetically), and then your `--query` parameter will show any of them that match the criteria.

To list the 10 latest objects, you would need to use something like:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents, &LastModified))[:10].Key'
```

However, this won't work if there are more than 1000 objects in the bucket or requested Prefix since `list_objects()` only returns a maximum of 1000 objects.

Comment: My bucket has more than 1000 objects. When I execute this query it returns a lot of items

Comment: Since your bucket has more than 1000 objects, the AWS CLI is not appropriate because you would need to create a loop to keep getting the next 1000 objects. You would need to write a script in a programming language like Python. Or, if you have a HUGE number of objects, you might consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.